# python pattern identifier? regex?

Tags: python, regex, list

So what I need is to identify the pattern " X" or "spaceCAPITAL" 
examples:

```
string="Hello World, This is KZ"
```

And the program would pick out:

```
example_list = [W,T,K]
```

Comment: Try to avoid naming a string `string`. It's a [built-in module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = "Hello World, This is KZ"
>>> re.findall(r'\s([A-Z])', strs)
['W', 'T', 'K']
```

Comment: {IDLE internal error in runcode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 236, in asyncqueue
    if threading.current_thread() != self.sockthread:
AttributeError: 'MyRPCClient' object has no attribute 'sockthread'}

Comment: is the error I'm encountering

Comment: @user2899835 That has nothing to do with the code I've posted.

Comment: I know, it doesn't like me importing re.

Comment: @user2899835 Google this: **AttributeError: 'MyRPCClient' object has no attribute 'sockthread'**, and you'll know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
re.findall(' ([A-Z])', string)
```